# Matplotlib with data from a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to plot data from a file using matplotlib. The catch is that the file could either have one variable or two variables in each line. There is also text in the file. An example file would be:

```
words
words
34, 34
132019, 232019
```

Below I have the code that I have created so far. The result of the code is nothing. No graph or errors. I was wondering if anyone knew the correct way to complete this task.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import re

regex = r'[\d]{1,3}, [\d]{1,3}'
result = []

with open('example.txt', 'r') as my_file:
# Read file into a list
lines = [i for i in my_file]
# Check length of list at least four items
    if len(lines) <= 4:
        lines1 = my_file.readlines()  # List containing all the lines as elements of the list

        date_line = lines1[4]

        len(date_line)

        if len(date_line) <= 10:
```

The part above is seeing if there is only one variable in the line of the file, or two.

```
            # Read in values and strip white space

            x = []
            y = []

            weight = lines[3].strip()
            date = lines[4].strip()

            weight1 = int(weight)
            date1 = int(date)

            x.append(date1)
            y.append(weight1)

            plt.plot(x, y)
            plt.xlabel("Dates")
            plt.ylabel("Weights")
            plt.title("Weight Chart")
            plt.show()

        else:

           lines = my_file.readlines()
           for line in lines:
                match = re.findall(regex, line)
                if match != []:
                    splitted = match[0].split(',')
                    mapped = list(map(float, splitted))
                    result.append(mapped)

                    plt.plot(result)
                    plt.xlabel("Dates")
                    plt.ylabel("Weights")
                    plt.title("Weight Chart")
                    plt.show()
```

Thanks so much for any help! I appreciate it!

Comment: You have `# Check length of list at least four items` `if len(lines) <= 4:`. Is this correct? Do you want `>=` instead? Also, although you don't have any output, you should throw in some print statements to find out what, if anything is being executed.

Answer (score 0):

You read the file with

```
lines = [i for i in my_file]
```

But you try to read the file again with `readlines`--there's nothing more to read! Just use `lines` again.